# Node.js how to execute command on remote windows server

Tags: node.js

I am developing an application using node.js(v8.1.4), express and angularjs. Node.js is installed in windows server 8 and I want to connect other windows servers using their respective credentials.

After connection is established, I want to execute commands on remote servers. But I do not know how to connect remote windows server or what package is available for windows connectivity.

For executing commands locally , I am using below code that is working fine,

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var execcommand = 'dir';
var myproccess = exec(execcommand); 
myproccess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log(data)
}
```

But I am not getting an idea how to connect remote windows with credentials and execute command.

Please help. I have been struggling with this for many days.

Thanks

Comment: I did not understand well I'm sorry...  
do you mean that you want to run the program with powershell or cmd?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.  I want to run the program with CMD.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SSH installed on each of the remote machines, you can execute a command in those servers by,

```
ssh <remote server ip or hostname> <command to execute>
```

However, you will need to setup the ssh keys in both machines in order to connect without password.

Comment: could you please guide me (or refer me any url) how to install ssh on windows server. I searched on net and it tells to install Putty. Is there any better way ?

Comment: Which version of Windows is installed on your servers?
Windows 10 has a built-in SSH server and client which you can enable: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/heres-how-to-enable-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-client/
For other versions of Windows, check this guide: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

Comment: Thanks @Thimira. I tried follow 2nd url and install openssh on Windows 8.1 but it seems too complicated.could you please refer me some simple steps to install and check connectivity from putty.

Comment: Hi @Thimira, I have installed openshh through "setupssh-7.4p1-1.exe" and it is working. But the problem is , i am able to execute linux command like "ls" but not windows command like "dir". I wanted to execute windows command on remote windows machine through node.js. please suggest how is it possible to execute windows command in ssh shell. I am using "simple-ssh" npm package in my node scripts.

Answer (score 0):

For the poor souls who have to work with Windows versions older than 10 (those who don't have built-in ssh servers), you can give [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) a try. Some servers seem to come pre-installed with it. Here's the general syntax:

```
psexec.exe \\<address> <command>
```